# "Add To Page" popup on application canvas

Tags: facebook, canvas

When you visit an application profile on FB, you can add that application to your page by clicking the "Add To Page" link, then a popup dialog appears. Is there a way I can make it so the users of my application can skip going to the application profile, and have the dialog pop up after clicking a link on the canvas page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to auto-trigger that popup, but you could use the API to add your app directly to the user's pages once you get the manage_pages permission from them

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs